# Javascript - Change border colour of form textbox when user enters something?

Tags: javascript

I have no code for this.

I'm just trying new things to my form. The required fields have a red border. I want them to go black when filled out. Would `onchange` be used?

Comment: Depending on when you want the border to change. You can use `onkeydown` or `onkeypress` if you want it to change immediately when the user begins to fill it out.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done entirely using CSS. (The "red" is already CSS most likely). Here's some code I like to use to give a nice "eased" glow to form elements.

```
input[type=text] {
    height: 30px; 
}

input[type=text], textarea {
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    color: #555;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
}

input[type=text]:focus, textarea:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
}
```